# Cannot edit data in an Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm developing a small Access 2003 DB with 2 forms.  The user first enters `FrmMain` and if a record interests them, they can go to `FrmDetails` (kind of like a 'drill-down' style). This second form allows the user to leave comments, change a few values, etc. and is called with the following code:

```
Private Sub Cmd_GoToDetailsForm_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
   DoCmd.OpenForm "FrmDetails", , , _
      "[TblF1-Main].[The_ID]=""" & Me.The_ID.Value & """"
End Sub
```

Here's the problem, **the user can't edit any of the fields in `FrmDetails`. Why not and can you suggest a fix?**.  More facts about my problem:

- When I open `FrmDetails` directly, I can edit them without a problem
- `FrmDetails` has no VBA code. It will soon, but not yet.
- `FrmDetails`'s recordsource is a table with all the default properties.
- This is the 2nd database I've designed that uses this model.  I've compared this broken db with the working db and I don't see any notable differences.

Comment: First off, `OpenForm` has a WhereCondition parameter that you can use in lieu of your With block to simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, mwolfe.  I updated my code as above, but I still have the problem.

Comment: If you open the form from your code but comment out the WhereCondition, does that make any difference?

Comment: No difference.  Good try, though. It feels like opening the form using `OpenForm` is overriding the `Allow Edits` property even though I'm using default settings wherever possible.

Comment: You could try adding a watch on `Forms!FrmDetails.AllowEdits` and break when value changes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that it works when you open FrmDetails directly?  Do you mean double-clicking on the form from the database window?  Because `DoCmd.OpenForm` with no optional parameters should do the same thing.

Comment: If you open using `DoCmd.OpenForm` with no parameters, then switch to Design view, then switch back to Form view, does that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer finally.  For no particular reason, I had set `FrmMain`'s `Record Lock`'s property to `All Records` (The default setting is `No Locks`).  Since both forms were based on the same table, I'm guessing that the 1st Form locked the records for the 2nd form. @mwolfe02, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looking to do something similar. Did you use no locks (I'm guessing a record lock would cause the same problem.) Do the two forms update data to the same field? Just wondered if the user could end up over-writing an entry in the detail with the main form.

Comment: Why would you open a form on a table you've already got loaded in a form? Is this to edit a different record of the same table? Also, in regard to locking, optimistic locking is by far the first choice with Access. I know it doesn't feel right, but I learned a long time ago that you start with optimistic locking (i.e., NoLocks) and escalate to something more restrictive only if you encounter problems that can't be resolved with stricter locking in place.

Comment: @Jeff, Although both forms are based off the same table, FrmMain doesn't have any editable fields (it just lists a few fields so the user can decide whether or not to enter that record).  So, the answer is No, there are no issues with overwriting data.

Comment: @David, This is a 'drill-down' style report.  FrmMain shows records in a 1-*line*-per-record (i.e. continuous) form with only a few fields.  After the user clicks on that record, they are taken to FrmDetails, a 1-*page*-per-record (i.e. single form) with all the rest of the data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why a pop-up form, then? Why not use two subforms on an unbound form, with the first being the list (like you already have) and the second being a single-record detail form, linked via LinkMaster to the PK of the record selected in the list form? This means when the user selects any record in the list form, the details will be loaded in the detail form -- no programming, no locking issues, not popup forms.

Answer (score 0):

Is FrmDetails being opened as a sub form of FrmMail?  If so, check whether the SubForm control is Locked or not.

After that, check whether the form FrmDetails has the property Allow Edits and Allow Additions are set to Yes or No.

Comment: It's not a SubForm.  Otherwise, I would have done all the linking in the properties. Also, Allow Edits=Yes, and Allow Additions=Yes.